# Find $\operatorname{Supp}_\mathbb Z(\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)$ and $\operatorname{Ass}_\mathbb Z(\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, fractions, integers, localization

> Let $R=\mathbb Z$ which is a ring and let $M=\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ which is an $R$-module.
>
> Calculate $\operatorname{Ass}(M)$ and $\operatorname{Supp}(M)$.

Recall that

- $\operatorname{Supp}(M)=\{p\in\operatorname{Spec}(R):M_p\ne0\}$
- $\operatorname{Ass}(M)=\{p\in\operatorname{Spec}(R):\exists 0\ne m\in M:\operatorname{Ann}(m)=p\}$
- $\forall m\in M,\operatorname{Ann}(m)=\{r\in R:rm=0\}$

I have succeeded to show that $\operatorname{Ass}(M)=\{p\mathbb Z:p\text{ is prime}\}$.

---

**EDIT:**

I deleted some of the previous question and I would like to add an attempt. I would like if someone could verify my answer;

Let $p\in\mathbb N$ be a prime. $1\notin\langle p\rangle$. Hence $(\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)_p\ni{{1\over p}+\mathbb Z\over 1}$.
$$
{{1\over p}+\mathbb Z\over 1}={\mathbb Z\over 1}\iff\exists t\notin\ p\mathbb Z:\mathbb Z=t\cdot{1\over p}+\mathbb Z
$$
So we conclude ${{1\over p}+\mathbb Z\over 1}\ne 0\Rightarrow p\mathbb Z\in\text{supp}(\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)$.

Let us check weather $\langle0\rangle\in\text{supp}(M)$ where $M=\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$.

Consider $p:=\langle0\rangle$;

$\mathbb Z_p=\mathbb Q $ because if ${a\over b}=_\mathbb Q{c\over d}\iff{a\over b }=_{\mathbb Z_p}{c\over d}$ and a similar calculation shows that $\mathbb Q\cong\mathbb Q_p$. Hence $M_p=(\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)_p=\mathbb Q_p/\mathbb Z_p\cong \mathbb Q/\mathbb Q=0$. Hence $\langle0\rangle\notin\text{supp}(M)$.

> We conclude: $\text{supp}(\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)=\{p\mathbb Z:p\text{ is prime}\}$.

Comment: I don't understand your last paragraph.  What does it mean to be an element of a zero?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard for me to understand what isn't compiling for you, but you're almost done.  The question remaining is: for which primes $p\in\rm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ do we have $\mathbb{Q}_p / \mathbb{Z}_p \neq 0$?

To sum up: $p\in\rm{Supp}(M)$ if and only if $\mathbb{Z}_p \neq \mathbb{Q}_p$.  Does this happen for $p=(0)$?  What about $p\neq (0)$?